# Регулярное выражение для поиска шестизначных чисел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте любители регулярных выражений

задача:
1. есть разный текст сообщениями с числами и без.
2. Нужно найти именно

```
$pattern = '/([1-9][0-9]{5})/i';
```

т.е. число начинается с числа с вариантами от 1 до 9 и пяти чисел от 0 до 9

Проблема:
как отсеять не нужные?
пример, не подходят: 
"42342535425234"
"задание 42342535425234 тест"

Подходят:
"123456"
"задание №123456 тест"
"задание №123456тест"
"задание123456тест"
"задание123456"

в этих примерах оджно быть найдено число 123456

как должен выглядеть $pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких случаях, когда границу слова `\b`, а также "якоря" начала (`^`) и конца строки (`$`) использовать невозможно, можно воспользоваться блоками предварительного просмотра назад и вперёд.

```
(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{5}(?!\d)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/4qC2eC/1)

**Подробности**:

- `(?<!\d)` - позиция в строке, *перед которой* нет цифры
- `[1-9]` - цифра от 1 до 9 (любая отличная от 0)
- `\d{5}` - пять любых цифр
- `(?!\d)` - позиция в строке, *после которой* нет цифры.

[PHP-демо](http://ideone.com/n3UsOm):

```
$arr = array("42342535425234", "задание 42342535425234 тест", "123456", "задание №123456 тест", "задание №123456тест", "задание123456тест", "задание123456");
$pattern = '~(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{5}(?!\d)~';
foreach ($arr as $s) {
    echo $s . ": " . preg_match($pattern, $s) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Результат:

```
42342535425234: 0
задание 42342535425234 тест: 0
123456: 1
задание №123456 тест: 1
задание №123456тест: 1
задание123456тест: 1
задание123456: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/(^|\D)([1-9][0-9]{5})($|\D)/i';
```

`\D` -  любой символ, не являющийся цифрой.

Comment: на чистой строке из 6 цифр сработает? когда на местах `\D` пусто?

Comment: Не сработает. Пофиксил.

Comment: в non-capturing group еще запихайте концы для полного счастия. `i` тоже можно убрать, смысла в нем здесь никакого.